# как передать несколько значений через url из Одного js файла в другой

Tags: javascript, json, url

Один из способов, чтобы передать значения из одного файла в другой без использования серверного программирования - прописать знак вопроса после файла и прибавить(наверное сказать правильнее конкатенировать) это значение. Одно значение срабатывает хорошо. А как передать несколько значений?

```
first.html:

<script src="first.js"></script>
<body>  
    <button id="btn">KNOPKA</button>
    </body>

first.js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);
     let arr = [5];
     let str = "Hello Vasya!";

function buttonClick() {
    arr = [1, 2, 3];
    str = "Hello Petya";
    location.href ='second.html?'+arr;
}

function init() {
    let button = document.getElementById("btn");
    button.addEventListener("click", function() {
        buttonClick()
    });
}

second.html:
<body>
    <script src="second.js"></script>       
    </body>

second.js:
let outcome = location.search.substring(1);
alert(outcome)
```

Еще подскажите, передача происходит в данном случае с использованием JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так.

```js
// first.js

function setVariables(variableArray) {
  const url = new URL(window.location);
  url.pathname = "second.html"; 
  
  variableArray.forEach(([name, value]) => {
    url.searchParams.set(name, value);
  });
  
  window.location = url;
}

setVariables([["name", "Vlad"], ["age", 29]]);

// second.js

function getVariables() {
  const result = Object.create(null);

  const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

  params.forEach((value, name) => result[name] = value);

  return result;
}

console.log(getVariables());
```